# Running scripts/commands from a host system in a chroot environment.

Tags: linux, shell, chroot, android

First of all, I have inside an android Operating System a chroot environment created using Linux Deploy. I am able to access it from Android using a terminal emulator and root permission. I would like to run a script inside it. However, when trying to run the script, or even normal shell commands, it doesn't executes and returns this error:

"No such file or directory"

So, I am wondering, is it there a way to execute, from the host within a chroot environment, commands/scripts? Has the problem to do with the proper setting of the environment PATH variable?

I am able to execute ls command within the chroot environment but when printing with the -la argument it doesn't even show the . and .. directories. Could someone explain why is this happening and how could we overcome this issue?

P.D.: I've posted this issue in unix/linux stack exchange because I thought it concerns more to it. However, if you recommend me to also post it in stackoverflow or any other, I am open to do so.

Comment: You must of course populate the chroot environment before chrooting into it. To run commands it must have `/bin`, `/sbin` etc. with the commands in them.

Comment: Actually, I can find them on the chroot environment. However, when executing it shows the error described above.

Comment: If you have a correctly populated the chroot environment (including libraries for example), have you tried invoking the commands using their full pathname?

Comment: I am currently trying to populate the chroot environment. I tried invoking the commands using their full pathname or even changing the PATH environment variable to search on the chroot bin but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have fully configured your chroot environment. Here are instructions for setting up a Debian chroot on Android:

- https://wiki.debian.org/ChrootOnAndroid

There are lots of other OS-specific instructions online for setting up a chroot, e.g.:

- [Ubuntu chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot)
- [Debian chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)
- [CentOS chroot](http://zaufi.github.io/administration/2014/06/10/howto-make-a-centos-chroot)

The bottom line is that you typically would install the programs into your chroot environment before trying to execute them. What have you done to setup your chroot?

Comment: I have just installed a linux image using linux deploy app, which as I understand created a chroot environment. I was able to enter this chroot environment through the terminal emulator. I Don't know if I was totally clear with this, maybe I should rephrase the question.

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasMartin Sure. Can you explain why you need (or want) to run scripts/programs from the host environment without installing them in the chrooted environment?

Comment: Sure, It comes really from the need to install rockchip's gstreamer plugins on linux, as I am working on a video processing project. When running the installation script for this plugins from the chroot environment which is accessed via VNC, it doesn't find some files, which I suppose are on the host system which can't be accessed. Therefore, I am trying to see if running the script on the host environment could fix this issue and install the plugins on the chroot's linux.

Comment: Why not install those files in the chroot environment?

Comment: In fact, I do not know what are those files I am missing because I supposed they were already there on the package one can download from github. It seems I need extra stuff which seems to be no documentation about.

Comment: In that case I think your question should probably just be about how to install that software - including dependencies. It's not clear that there's anything about that that's specific to chroot. Maybe update your question to include the error messages that you're getting?